# How to use Azure Spot instances on Databricks

Tags: azure-databricks, spot-instances

Spot instances brings the posibility to use free resources in the cloud paying a lower price, however if the cloud demand is increased your resources will be dealocated. This is very usefull for non critical workloads whenever you can aford to loose some of the work done. More info [2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/) [3](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/spot/)

Databricks has the posibility to run [spot instances on AWS](https://docs.databricks.com/administration-guide/capacity-planning/cmbp.html) but there is no documentation about how to do it on Azure.

Is it possible to run Databricks clusters on Azure Spot instances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible but not using Databricks UI. To use Azure spot instances on Databricks you need to use [databricks cli](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/index.html).

> *Note*
>
> With the cli tool is it possible to administrate -create, edit, delete- clusters and instances-pools. However, to simplify the process, I'll focus on editing an existing cluster.

You can install databricks cli using `pip install databricks-cli` and configure your credentials with `databricks configure --token`. For more information, visit [databricks documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/index.html).

Run the command `datbricks clusters list` to know the ID of the cluster you want to modify:

```sh
$ datbricks clusters list
0422-112415-fifes919  Big Spark3     TERMINATED
0612-341234-jails230  Normal Spark3  TERMINATED
0212-623261-mopes727  Small 7.6      TERMINATED
```

In my case, I have 3 clusters. First column is the cluster ID, second one is the name of the cluster. Last column is the state.

The command `databricks cluster get` generates the cluster config in json format. Let's generate the json file to modify it:

```
databricks clusters get --cluster-id 0422-112415-fifes919 > /tmp/my_cluster.json
```

This file contains all the configuration related to the cluster like name, instance type, owner... In our case we are looking for the `azure_attributes` section. You will see something similar to:

```json
...
"azure_attributes": {
    "first_on_demand": 1,
    "availability": "ON_DEMAND_AZURE",
    "spot_bid_max_price": -1.0
  },
...
```

We need to change the `availability` to `SPOT_WITH_FALLBACK_AZURE` and `spot_bid_max_price` with our bid price. Edit the file with your favorite tool. The result should be something like:

```json
...
  "azure_attributes": {
    "first_on_demand": 1,
    "availability": "SPOT_WITH_FALLBACK_AZURE",
    "spot_bid_max_price": 0.4566
  },
...
```

Once modified, just update the cluster with the new configuration file using `databricks clusters edit`:

```
databricks clusters edit --json-file /tmp/my_cluster.json
```

Now, everytime you start the cluster, the workers will be spot instances.To confirm this, you can go to the configuration tab inside the worker VM that is allocated in the resource group managed by databricks. You will see the Azure spot is active and with the price configured.

[image]

Databricks on AWS has [more configuration options](https://docs.databricks.com/administration-guide/clusters/policies.html) like `SPOT` for the `availability` field. However, until the documentation is released we'll need to wait or configure with try-error approach.